# Remove sort mode for treeview

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

To make my treeview sorting as a new mode i want. I using the following command :

```
TreeView1.TreeViewNodeSorter = New NodeSorter()
```

But i don't know how to convert the sort mode back to normal/default. I've try :

```
TreeView1.TreeViewNodeSorter = Nothing
```

But nothing happen. How to convert the sort mode back to normal without writing a new sorter class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a quick look at the reference source:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeView.cs

It seems that by default, `TreeViewNodeSorter` is `null`.  When you set a custom implementation, the `Sort()` method is called.  This isn't called when you set it back to `null`.

I'd suggest setting `TreeViewNodeSorter` to `null` and then calling `Sort()`

Comment: I've try but this not work. However i added a new class to resolve it to not waste time. Anyway, thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

TreeView1.Sorted = false; // seems to work fine

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.